# Simple XML return with PHP and DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml

I am building a simple api to Post/Return XML for my app. Here is the code:

```
        $returnData = array (
        "ResultCode" => "0",
        "ResultString" => "uppdated"
        );
        $xml = new DOMDocument();
        $dateInfoElement = $xml->createElement("versionCheckResult");
        foreach ($returnData as $key => $value) {
            $xmlNode = $xml->createElement($key,$value);
            $dateInfoElement->appendChild($xmlNode);
            }
        $xml->appendChild($dateInfoElement); 
        echo $xml;
```

Sadly, I am getting no return, not a thing. Php is not my strong side but it seemed easier than working with Node.JS and mongoDB. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using DOMDocument, you need to use this method to display your XML as a string : [DOMDocument::saveXML()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php)

```php
    $returnData = array (
    "ResultCode" => "0",
    "ResultString" => "uppdated"
    );
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $dateInfoElement = $xml->createElement("versionCheckResult");
    foreach ($returnData as $key => $value) {
        $xmlNode = $xml->createElement($key,$value);
        $dateInfoElement->appendChild($xmlNode);
        }
    $xml->appendChild($dateInfoElement); 
    echo $xml->saveXML(); //This should works as expected
```